# read in knockout computable not always firing with extender

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, subscriber

this might be easiest to describe with a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32190/

I have an observable called price which has an extender so that it rounds to two digits and does not allow non numeric.

I have a writable computed observable that puts a dollar sign in front of it.

however if the extender returns 0. the second time it happens $0 is not returned to the textbox (the computed observable) so if I type hello world in the textbox (computed observable) the price correctly reports 0 and the formatted price shows $0. however if I clear it out and type in hello world a second time. this time price is still $0 but the formatted price textbox is showing hello world (even though formatted price is reporting $0).  must be missing a notification somewhere?

here is the code.

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
  //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
  var result = ko.pureComputed({
    read: target, //always return the original observables value
    write: function(newValue) {
      var current = target(),
        roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
        newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(+newValue),
        valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

      //only write if it changed
      if (valueToWrite !== current) {
        target(valueToWrite);
      } else {
        //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
        if (newValue !== current) {
          target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
        }
      }
    }
  }).extend({
    notify: 'always'
  });

  //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
  result(target());

  //return the new computed observable
  return result;
};


function model() {
  var self = this;

  this.price = ko.observable('29.01').extend({
    numeric: '2'
  });
  this.formattedPrice = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      return '$' + this.price()
    },
    write: function(value) {
      value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
      this.price(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
    },
    owner: this
  });
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seemed to work for me was extending the `formattedPrice` computed variable to always notify and modify the write method to just pass in the value rather than checking for isNaN; your extender does this anyway and forcing a 0 makes it so that your `if (newValue !== current)` test never returns true as newValue and current will always be 0 in this scenario (NaN !== 0 *will* pass the check):

```
  this.formattedPrice = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      return '$' + this.price()
    },
    write: function(value) {
      value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
      this.price(value); //just pass in nan or the value so the extender can check/notify if newValue !== current
    },
    owner: this
  }).extend({
    notify: 'always'
  });
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32192/